# Parsing on jq with_entries

Tags: jq

I have the following data
Command output:

```
| jq '.rrsets[]'
```

```json
{
  "comments": [],
  "name": "name1.",
  "records": [
    {
      "content": "10.10.10.10",
      "disabled": false
    }
  ],
  "ttl": 60,
  "type": "A"
}
{
  "comments": [],
  "name": "name2.",
  "records": [
    {
      "content": "20.20.20.20",
      "disabled": false
    }
  ],
  "ttl": 60,
  "type": "CNAME"
}
```

I want to get names where type is A.
Help, tell me how to do this?

```
| jq '.rrsets[] | with_entries(select(.key== "name", .value == "A"))'
```

```json
{
  "name": "name1."
}
{
  "name": "name2.",
  "type": "A"
}
```

Displays all the lines, but I only need where type = A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but wouldn't simply `... | select(.type == "A")` do the trick?

```sh
... | jq '.rrsets[] | select(.type == "A")'
```

```json
{
  "comments": [],
  "name": "name1.",
  "records": [
    {
      "content": "10.10.10.10",
      "disabled": false
    }
  ],
  "ttl": 60,
  "type": "A"
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/CEGIy_My8m)

And then just get the `.name` if you want only that (using `-r` to get rid of the JSON formatting):

```sh
... | jq -r '.rrsets[] | select(.type == "A").name'
```

```
name1.
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/ukZR0rAqlF)

Comment: Thank you, yes this is what I need =)) Something I went in the wrong direction. Thank you!!